# Java — How to find all valid combinations for a digital clock with hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, clock, digital

I need to fill a String array in Java with all possible combinations for a digital clock (but only as HHMMSS instead of HH:MM:SS) like these:

> 000000 000001 010000 235903

Invalid ones would be:

> 240000 000160 006000

and so on.

Is there an easier way to do this than convert the numbers from 0 to 999.999 to properly formatted Strings (from 000000 to 999999) and remove all the invalid ones?

This kind of the nested loops solution I was trying to avoid:

```
String[] arr = new String[24 * 60 * 60];

int index = 0;

for (int hours = 0; hours < 24; hours++) {
    for (int minutes = 0; minutes < 60; minutes++) {
        for (int seconds = 0; seconds < 60; seconds++) {
            
            arr[index] = String.format("%02d%02d%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `java.time` package:

```java
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss");
var hms = new String[24 * 60 * 60];
for (var i = 0; i < hms.length; i++) {
    hms[i] = formatter.format(LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(i));
}
```

---

Three nested loops:

```java
var hms = new String[24 * 60 * 60];
var index = 0;
for (var h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
    for (var m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
        for (var s = 0; s < 60; s++) {
            hms[index++] = String.format("%02d%02d%02d", h, m, s);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Single loop, using `format` to format time in Milliseconds (not so sure if that is recommended):

```java
var hms = new String[24 * 60 * 60];
for (var i = 0; i < hms.length; i++) {
    hms[i] = String.format("%TH%1$TM%1$TS", i * 1000L);
}
```

Comment: The second version looks very nice, thanks!

Comment: but (the now third) is kind of a hack (interpreting milliseconds as an *instant*)

Answer (score 1):

## Nested loops

You know there are twenty-four hours, 0 through 23.

You know there are sixty minutes possible, 0 through 59.

And there are 60 seconds, if we ignore [Leap Second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), 0 through 59.

Do you can set up the nested `for` loops. Canonically, we often use these single characters as the names of the counter in each loop: `i`, `j`, and `k`. But in your case I world use names of `hour`, `minute`, `second`.

To most efficiently build up the text, use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object.

I’m not show the actual code to preserve for you the joy of completing your own schoolwork assignment.

Comment: Funny story, CS teacher here, and I'm looking for a way to avoid using nested loops :) I was thinking about a regex to match valid combinations, but Arrays.fill() doesn't seem to work this way :)

Answer (score 1):

No loops at all:

```
java.util.stream.LongStream.
           range(0, 24 * 60 * 60).
           mapToObj(x -> java.time.LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(x)).
           collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()).
           forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss"))));
```